formio override selectboxes component template
I am new to formio and just started using it and i read the documentation on how to customize its native templates with our own highlighted on this link
Templates.current = {
  input: {
    form: (ctx) => '<div>My custom template</div>'
  },
};

and as per the theory, it seems like we need to pass componentname (which is input here) as a key of the json for which overriding is needed and then under the form key within the sub-json, we need to pass function which accepts context (ctx) and returns html with some manipulation using that ctx.
I have used the same thing but with no effect in frontend. So basically, I have some code somewhere where this component json is used.
{
  label: 'somelabel',
  selectThreshold: 0.3,
  
  calculateValue: "value = a+ b",
  validate: {
    onlyAvailableItems: false,
  },
  key: 'productAccessories',
  properties: {
    triggerprop: 'orderData',
  },
  type: 'selectboxes',
  inputType: "checkbox",
  indexeddb: {
    filter: {},
  },
  input: true,
},

So I thought I would need to pass selectboxes as key instead of input and tried like that. Here I am using Formio.Templates as i am using it as cdn in global scope, but this did not change anything. and then also tried after changing from selectboxes to checkbox with no luck at all.
Formio.Templates.current = {
      selectboxes: {
        form: (ctx) => '<div>My custom template</div>'
      },
};

// above did not work not sure why

Can anyone please help on this topic?
Formio library version that I am using is 4.13.0-rc.22.
